# Postgres psycopg2 DatabaseError on CHECK EXISTS on multiprocessing application

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using Postgres and psycopg2 as my driver in a multiprocessing application. In only 2 processes I am getting this error (I've tried 8 and it blows up pretty fast).

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='{0}');".format(name))
DatabaseError: error with no message from the libpq

LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
```

Googling this error message was no help since there are several reasons why that error can occur. It is possible that other transactions are happening on other processes, but they each create their own database connection. I'm also closing the database connection after each process is complete and reconnecting when it is restarted.

My theory is that there are a lot of database commands happening at the same time and postgres doesn't like this for whatever reason. I'm not sure how to solve this since the application has to run this way.

Comment: Anything of note in the *Postgres* log? That may help shed some more light on the specific reason for the error.

Comment: The above code is what I get in the log. Error on SELECT EXISTS and unexpected EOF.

Comment: Hmm... if you're suspecting too many connections, you could try tuning your *Postgres* server to accept more (assuming the hardware isn't already maxed out in terms of CPU and memory). See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server